# when allocating memory for an array dynamically (in C), what does the (int *) cast do?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc, allocation

C noob here. When declaring an array during runtime, I've seen two methods for doing so. Can someone please explain the (int *) cast in the second one?

```
// first way
int numberElements = 5;
int *pointer = malloc(numberElements * sizeof(int));

// second way
...
int *pointer = (int *)malloc(numberElements * sizeof(int));
```

I just don't see what the (int *) cast is doing. With first the allocation, the array can be filled like this...

```
// first way cont.
... 
for (int i = 0; i < numberElements; i += 1){
    pointer[i] = 0;\
}
```

is this not true for the second? what would you have to do differently?

Comment: You shouldn't. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1009479

Comment: "what does the (int *) cast do?" It shows that whoever wrote this, has a C++ background ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast does nothing. A void pointer can be assigned to any pointer without an explicit cast.

[AND you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). The C99 (or C90, C11) standard does not require the cast.

Answer (score 0):

malloc()'s return type is a void *

So when it gets assigned it needs to get converted to an int*

Doing (int*) does this explicitly.  If that's not done, it is done implicitly by the compiler.

A pointer is a pointer, it's only the compiler trying to give you type safety that has any bearing at all.  With some compilers with certain flags you'll get a warning if the explicit (int*) cast isn't there.  The actual resulting compiled code is exactly the same in both cases.

So as Mitch said, it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: The result needs to be *converted*, not cast, to `int*`. A "cast" is an explicit operator, consisting of a type name in parentheses. `int *ptr = malloc(...);` converts the `void*` result to `int*` without a cast, an implicit conversion.

Comment: @KeithThompson Good point, answer edited.